# Broken laptop fan - best solution

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, temperature

The temperature sensor of my laptop fan is broken, the motherboard doesn't give the fan a signal to start/stop, and therefore it doesn't start anymore which causes my laptop to thermal shutdown due to overheating.

Since it's out if warranty, I am thinking of a few solutions, which one is the best?

- Disassemble my laptop and connect the fan directly to the power, making it spin all of the time(I know and don't mind that this will drastically shorten my battery life; it's hardly ever running on battery.)
- Buy a USB laptop cooler/laptop cooling pad; **Is this enough to completely replace a broken fan?**
- Attempt to fix the temperature sensor
- Any other solutions?

Comment: The first thing you should consider is how old your laptop is. Is it still worth trying to fix it, or perhaps better to just replace the laptop alltogether?

Comment: Sorry, I've voted to close this as it is entirely opinion based - and it depends on way to many variables, including how cluefull you are, the value of your time, the value of your laptop, how hot ambient temperature is.   That said, a USB laptop/cooler pad cant completely replace a broken fan (but it might be enough to stop the system shutting down)

Comment: @LPChip it's 2 years old, warranty expired literally a month ago. I don't want to buy a new one yet if there's a hacky, money-saving solution. (I fixed my previous one's broken power jack using nothing more than a paperclip; which melt)

Comment: @davidgo ambient temp is 25° C, laptop shuts down at 115° C. It's pretty valuable as it's my only pc

Comment: Based on your other comments logic dictates connecting the fan so it runs all the time as the most appropriate solution then - assuming its the sensor thats faulty rather then the fan (and a faulty fan seems, to me, more likely)

Comment: @davidgo I'm quite sure it's the sensor as there are moments that it randomly starts spinning very hard; so the fan itself still works. A faulty fan to me would be a broken blade or something

Comment: Ahh, but fans have logic in them to control/measure their own speed - I posit that it is this circuitry that may be faulty.

Comment: @davidgo ooh didn't know that.. would it be possible to disable this?

Comment: I think what he is suggesting is testing the fan itself, to see if it will reliably stay running when given the power to do so. If it is only the fan, which small fans die early , then it is easier to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Cooling pad definitely wont be enough.

If you have the saavy to fix that sensor I'd say that'd be your best bet if you're certain that's the culprit. The risk of ruining the board, however, may be quite high.

Second best option is your suggestion of having the fan set to run always on - but again, only if you feel comfortable enough performing that workaround.

The third option - replace the entire motherboard. If this laptop is just a hair out of warranty but expensive enough to warrant it this might be a relatively cost effective option.

Comment: With attempt to fix the sensor I meant buy a new one and replace it, if I even figure out where it is. And yes I'm quite sure it's the sensor as there are moments that it randomly starts spinning very hard; so the fan itself still works